# Dynamic Conditional Variables

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm attempting to create documents of a priori unknown length that is determined by a set of conditions.  I'm generating LaTeX variables, including conditional variables, using Python.  Within a variables LaTeX file, I have something resembling:

```
\newcommand{\VariableList}{VariableOne,VariableTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubOne}{SomeValueOne}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueOne}
\newif\ifVariableOneCondOne
\VariableOneCondOnetrue
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubOne}{SomeValueTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueTwo}
\newif\ifVariableTwoCondOne
\VariableTwoCondOnefalse
```

Where the number of variables are not known.  I loop over each variable and have some text that includes the values dynamically defined by the variables.

```
\foreach \n in \VariableList{
Here is some text with \inputnum{\n}{SubOne} and \inputnum{\n}{SubTwo}.
}
```

Where I have defined:

```
\newcommand{\inputnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname #1#2\endcsname}
```

How can I define a similar command to take advantage of the conditional variables I have defined above?  For example, I tried:

```
\newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname if#1#2\endcsname}
```

using the logic that the macro would replace

```
\inputcondnum{\n}{CondOne}
```

with the following

```
\ifVariableOneCondOne
```

but that does not seem to work.  Any suggestions on how to use these dynamically generated conditional variables?

Here is a minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Command to generate variables
\newcommand{\inputnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname if#1#2\endcsname}

% Variable definitions
\newcommand{\VariableList}{VariableOne,VariableTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubOne}{SomeValueOne}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueOne}
\newif\ifVariableOneCondOne
\VariableOneCondOnetrue
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubOne}{SomeValueTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueTwo}
\newif\ifVariableTwoCondOne
\VariableTwoCondOnefalse


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in \VariableList{
Here is some text with \inputnum{\n}{SubOne} and \inputnum{\n}{SubTwo}. 

\inputcondnum{\n}{CondOne} Include this text if true \else Include this text if false. \fi
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See above for the test file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally best to avoid the issue but you can make it work as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Command to generate variables
\newcommand{\inputnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname if#1#2\endcsname}

% Variable definitions
\newcommand{\VariableList}{VariableOne,VariableTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubOne}{SomeValueOne}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueOne}
\newif\ifVariableOneCondOne
\VariableOneCondOnetrue
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubOne}{SomeValueTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueTwo}
\newif\ifVariableTwoCondOne
\VariableTwoCondOnefalse


\begin{document}

\foreach \n in \VariableList{
Here is some text with \inputnum{\n}{SubOne} and \inputnum{\n}{SubTwo}. 

\iftrue\csname fi\endcsname\inputcondnum{\n}{CondOne} Include this text if true \else Include this text if false. \fi
}
\end{document}
```

---

the issue is that TeX skips over `\if....`\fi constructs but it needs to see `\if...` at the same time as it does not do expansion while skipping over "false" sections.

Note also that the `\expandafter` are not needed in

```
\newcommand{\inputnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname if#1#2\endcsname}
```

in the first case, because `\csname` expands its content anyway so forcing expansion earlier with `\expandafter` results in the same name being constructed. In the second case the `\expandafter` does nothing at all as `i` is not expandable.

Comment: This solution absolutely works, but if you could define inputcondnum, how would you do it to preserve the same variable definitions in the preamble and minimize the code when calling the variable?  In other words, how would you define the command \inputcondnum so that it works as \iftrue\csname fi\endcsname\inputcondnum ?

Comment: Up to you, just only changing the line \newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\expandafter\csname if#1#2\endcsname}

Comment: @jfbu 17 minutes ago I was eating dinner, I added some notes about that, then noticed your comment just now:-)

Comment: @DrTRD if you want to use the `\if..\else\fi` syntax I would use `\if\inputnum{\n} yes\else no\fi`  where `inputnum` was defined to be `00` for cases that should be true and `01` for cases that you want to be false`.  (then you don't need any `\newif`

Comment: This suggestion really is parsimonious.  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why including the first `0` in the variable? Wouldn't `\if0\inputnum{\n}no\else yes\fi` be closer to python (meaning a value not 0 is true)?

Comment: @Skillmon oh possibly but using `00` and `01` has a long history (eg the texbook discusses some issues with it, which lead to the introduction of `\iftrue`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know this is an old question, but would you mind clarifying/elaborating a little on what you mean by "_TeX skips over \if....\fi constructs but it needs to see \if... at the same time as it does not do expansion while skipping over "false" sections_"? Your answer addressed the issues I was having perfectly, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding _why_ it works the way it does. Thanks!

Comment: @TheMac possibly better to ask a new question  but easy way to see why you can not hide conditionals `\iffalse a \else b \fi `  expands to `b`, `\iftrue a \else b \fi ` expands to`a` but if you have `\def\zelse{\else}` then only the true version works: `\iftrue a \zelse b \fi ` expands to`a` but  `\iffalse a \zelse b \fi `  expands to nothing as tex skips past `\zelse` while skipping over the false branch, so never sees the `\else`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, thanks, I get it now! In this specific case, the issue comes from the fact that the `\foreach` loop actually contains a disguised `\if...\fi` construct, which fails when it skips expanding the `\inputcondnum` but still sees the subsequent `\else` and `\fi`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this old question to leave a somewhat cleaner solution, just for posterity.

If, for whatever reason, you're committed to the `\csname if...\endcsname` construct (say, if you need to pass the names of already-defined conditionals), a much cleaner solution than the `\iftrue\csname fi\endcsname\inputcondnum...` hackery is to simply put the entire `\if...\fi` construct inside a macro.

The problem arises when your `\csname if...\endcsname` is nested inside another conditional—in this case, a hidden one controlling the `\foreach` loop. To elaborate a little on David's answer, when executing a conditional, TeX does some bookkeeping to track of nested `\if...\fi`s. If a conditional is false, it skips ahead to the next `\fi` (or next `\else`), but it needs to know *which* `\fi` to skip to. When the skipped text contains a second `\if...\fi`, it takes note, and makes sure to continue past the inner `\fi` and keep skipping ahead to the outer `\fi`. *However*, it doesn't perform any expansions while it's looking for its `\fi`. As a result, when the inner `\if...` is hidden inside another macro (like `\csname...\endcsname`) but the `\fi` is still in plain view, its bookkeeping gets thrown off, and everything goes haywire.

The solution is to make sure the `\if...` *and* the matching `\fi` are *both* tucked away inside a macro, making sure one is never seen without the other. In your case, you'd modify the minimal example to something like this (with a little formatting for readability):

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{10pt} %readability
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Command to generate variables
\newcommand{\inputnum}[2]{\csname #1#2\endcsname}
\newcommand{\inputcondnum}[2]{\csname if#1#2\endcsname}

% Variable definitions
\newcommand{\VariableList}{VariableOne,VariableTwo}

\newcommand{\VariableOneSubOne}{SomeValueOne}
\newcommand{\VariableOneSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueOne}
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubOne}{SomeValueTwo}
\newcommand{\VariableTwoSubTwo}{SomeOtherValueTwo}

\newif\ifVariableOneCondOne
\newif\ifVariableTwoCondOne
\VariableOneCondOnetrue
\VariableTwoCondOnefalse

%COMMAND TO TEST CONDITIONAL AND EXECUTE DESIRED CODE
\newcommand{\testcondnum}[4]{\inputcondnum{#1}{#2} #3 \else #4 \fi}

\begin{document}

%A simple implementation

{\bfseries Simple}:

\foreach \n in \VariableList{%
    \texttt{\textbackslash n} is \n.\\%
    Here is some text with \inputnum{\n}{SubOne} and \inputnum{\n}{SubTwo}. \\%
    \testcondnum{\n}{CondOne}{Include this text if true.}{Include this text if false.}

}

%If you want vary what's going on inside the conditional,
%re-define a macro on each pass through the loop with the
% relevant code to execute. You'll probably want to define 
%it with \def here, since \def doesn't care about overwriting 
%old commands. With \newcommand and \renewcommand, you'd need
%to worry about using one on the first pass and the other 
%on subsequent passes.

%Of course, you could also just keep feeding the "Include 
%this..." bits straight into testcondnum, but for more 
%complicated code, using macros will probably be easier.

{\bfseries Dynamic}:

\foreach \n in \VariableList{    
    \def\dothisiftrue{Include this text if \n CondOne is true.}
    \def\dothisiffalse{Include this text if \n CondOne is false.}  
    \texttt{\textbackslash n} is \n.\\%
    Here is some text with \inputnum{\n}{SubOne} and \inputnum{\n}{SubTwo}. \\%
    \testcondnum{\n}{CondOne}{\dothisiftrue}{\dothisiffalse}

}

\end{document}
```

Compiling yields:

[image]